# Flask teardown_request lose efficacy

Tags: flask, pycharm

In my Flask code, I used teardown_request is used to handle exceptions, which is effective when I use pycharm to run my code. When I run it directly from the command line, this hook function fails. May I ask if anyone can help me

The Pseudocode is as follows：

```
def record_exception(error: BaseException):
  if error:
    stack_info = traceback.format_exc()
    current_app.logger.log(logging.ERROR, msg=str(error), stack_info=stack_info)

def init_loggers(app: Flask) -> None:  
   app.teardown_request(record_exception)
```

When I use pycharm(python -m flask run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 6001), I can output logs normally, but when I run from the command line, I cannot output logs

I also tried vscode and couldn't input the log properly

Comment: I found that it was caused by running in different directories, but I don't know what the reason is。 PYTHONPATH='/Users/cc/src', when I run code in the 'src' can output log. when i in 'cc' is faild